# JQuery autogeocomplete set string length

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api, geocoding

I am using JQuery autogeocomplete and basically the lat_id and the lng_id strings are too long after the .

I need to set it so it's no more that 6 digits after the dot.

For example:

```
Before:
-1.1501888001110125
After
-1.150188
```

Is this possible or if not, is there a way round it?

Comment: should that not be -1.150189 ? or do you not want rounding - and you know the marker on the map will move (ie its not as accurate)

Comment: No, don't want to round it. Just want to take off the extra digits after the points to only leave 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
var mystring = "-1.1501888001110125";
var newstring = mystring.substr(0,(mystring.indexOf('.') + 7));
```

(its 7 because of "." plus 6 characters)

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/2xrNG/)

trimming an `input` :

```
$('#inputid').change(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $thisval = $this.val();
    if ($thisval.indexOf('.') > 0 && $thisval.length > 7) {
        $this.val($thisval.substr(0, ($thisval.indexOf('.') + 7)));
    }
});​
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/2xrNG/1/)

Comment: The only bad thing in this solution is that you cut the number and not round it. If you have 1.50188899999999999 it will be 1.501888 and not 1.501889 what it would be if you round it. In some scenarios you want that in some you don't.

Comment: @S.Visser look at the comments on the OPs question - "no rounding" and its a string not a number so `substr` is more effective

Comment: sorry, did not saw the comments. just saw this in his post "Is this possible or if not, is there a way round it?". But beside that its a good thing to notice for people that come here by search. Btw it was not a way to say that your code is bad or something ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
function roundNumber(num, dec) {
    var result = Math.round(num*Math.pow(10,dec))/Math.pow(10,dec);
    return result;
}

alert(​roundNumber(-1.32423423421421312​, 6))
​
```

Output: http://jsfiddle.net/PfNgh/